# How to use different --workdir for different hosts in GNU parallel

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-parallel

I want to execute my `script.sh` on local machine and on remote machine. However, on local machine the `script.sh` file is inside `~/dir1/`and on remote machine is inside `/dir2`.

What I tried was: inside `~/dir1/`on local machine I run:

```
  parallel --workdir /dir2 -S remotemachine -S : ./script.sh ::: someargs
```

On remote machine runs fine, but on local machine parallel also tries to run `script.sh` inside `/dir2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A job does not know on which server it will be run. This is (among other things) due to `--retries` which will retry the same job, but on a different server.

So GNU Parallel does not have a way to make the `--workdir` different depending on server (apart from the relative dirs: . and ...).

So what *can* you do instead?

If one of the dirs only exists on one of the machines, then you can `cd` to that just before running the script. The `cd` will fail on the machine which does not have the dir:

```
parallel -S server1,: 'cd dir-on-both; cd dir-on-one; script.sh' ::: some args
```

Use a common symlink:

```
ssh server1 ln -s dir1 link1 
ln -s dir2 link1
parallel --workdir link1/ -S server1,: script.sh ::: some args
```

If it is only due to the executable, set PATH to include both dirs:

```
PATH=$PATH:dir1:dir2
parallel --env PATH -S server1,: script.sh ::: some args
```

Comment: i liked all your suggestions but for me the easiest was the first one. As a tip, i redirected cd stderr to /dev/null

`parallel -S server1,: 'cd dir-on-both; cd dir-on-one 2> /dev/null; script.sh' ::: some args`